# Android - SMS BroadcastReceiver Working on Emulator but Not on Phone

Tags: android

I just wanted to know why my simple sms receiver works on my emulator(2.3) but not working on my phone(2.3).

My simple program will show a toast whenever I receive a new SMS.
It is showing on the emulator, and again not on the phone.

I tried two emulator and it works.

Here are the codes.

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("A new message just arrived.");
    Toast.makeText(context, "weee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.smsreceiver"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.smsreceiver.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hello @Akdeniz, I found the problem. It is because of GO SMS. They are aborting the SMS Broadcast after they process the received message.

Answer (score 1):

Your BROADCAST RECEIVER is aborted.
adding priority will solve the problem.

```
<receiver>
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
<action: .... >
</receiver>
```

set priority in your manifest. this should do.